# songs by Mozart and Beethoven?

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary

Is the word "songs" properly used in the following?

> By the 1700s, European glass harp masters could play songs by Mozart and Beethoven on the instruments.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Although there are (rare) exception, the words "song" implies singing.

The word you want here is `piece`.

> By the 1700s, European glass harp masters could play **pieces** by Mozart and Beethoven on the instruments.